# ¿No me da la respuesta correcta en C++?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Hice un pequeño programa donde puedo elevar al cubo un número y también puedo verificar si un número es par o impar. Al intentar verificar si el número es impar o par y este es demasiado largo me lo reconoce como un numero impar. A continuación  les muestro el código:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int opc, n2;
    float n1, cubo;
    cout<<"\tBienvenidos al modulo de Matematicas";
    cout<<"\n1. Cubo de un numero";
    cout<<"\n2. Numero par o impar";
    cout<<"\n3. Salir";
    cout<<"\nOpcion: "; cin>>opc;

    switch(opc){
        case 1:
            cout<<"Digite un numero: "; cin>>n1;
            cubo = pow(n1,3);
            cout<<"El cubo de su numero es: "<<cubo;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Digite un numero entero: "; cin>>n2;
            if(n2%2==0){
                cout<<"Su numero es par";
            }
            else if(n2==0){
                cout<<"Su numero es par";
            }
            else{
                cout<<"Su numero es impar";
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Al intentar con la opción 2,  y después digito el número 777777777777777777777772 me lo marca como un número **impar** sabiendo que un número es par cuando **El último dígito es 0, 2, 4, 6 u 8 o cualquier entero que pueda ser divido exactamente entre dos.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Esto es lo que sucede

Si introduces un número extremadamente grande como, por ejemplo, `777777777777777777777772`  en una variable de tipo entero en C++ se producirán resultados no deseados porque supera con creces el límite establecido para almacenar dicho número. Veamos varios ejemplos a continuación:

**Variable numérica declarada con `int`**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int num;
  cout << "Ingrese un número gigante: "; cin >> num;

  cout << "num => " << num << endl; // num => 2147483647
  return 0;
}
```

Si al ejecutar el programa, el usuario ingresa `777777777777777777777772` el resultado será `num => 2147483647`.

**Variable numérica declarada sin signo (`unsigned int`)**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  unsigned int num;
  cout << "Ingrese un número gigante: "; cin >> num;

  cout << "num => " << num << endl; // num => 4294967295
  return 0;
}
```

Allí podemos observar que se sigue truncando, aunque con un número ligeramente más grande.

**Entero sin signo más grande en C++ (`unsigned long long int`):**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Definamos el entero positivo más grande que podamos en C++
  unsigned long long int num;
  __int64_t num2;

  cout << "Ingrese un número gigante: "; cin >> num;
  cout << "Ingrese otra vez un número gigante: "; cin >> num2;

  cout << "num => " << num << endl; // num => 18446744073709551615
  cout << "num2 => " << num2 << endl; // num2 => 9223372036854775807
  return 0;
}
```

Si observamos el código anterior podemos observar que `777777777777777777777772` se trunca a `18446744073709551615` o `9223372036854775807` en el tipo de datos `__int64_t` porque todavía supera el entero más grande que podemos definir en C++. Si definimos el tipo de datos `__int128_t` se producirán errores al compilar, al menos, en el compilador que utilizo: `gcc´ de Linux.

Para ese caso, se deberá crear un nuevo tipo de datos que supere ese límite o utilizar una biblioteca como alternativa para ello, como por ejemplo [InfInt](https://sercantutar.github.io/infint/), aunque existen otras que cumplen el mismo objetivo. La biblioteca la puedes descargar en [GitHub](https://github.com/sercantutar/infint).

### Implementación de la biblioteca `InfInt`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "infInt.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  // Observe que el tipo de datos que  vamos a definir
  // es un entero de tipo InfInt, dado que recibe el nombre 
  // de la biblioteca:
  InfInt num;
  cout << "Ingese un número gigante: "; cin >> num;

  cout << "num => " << num << endl; // num => 777777777777777777777772

  // Realicemos una prueba:
  if ( num % 2 == 0 ) {
    cout << "El número " << num << " es par" << endl;
  }else {
    cout << "El número " << num << " es impar" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Aquí nos encontramos con el resultado esperado.

Comment: No deberías usar los tipos `__xxxx`, son símbolos reservados para el funcionamiento interno del compilador.

Answer (score 3):

En lenguajes de [tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte) como C++ cada variable tiene un tipo fijado y permanente. Cada tipo de datos numérico tiene un rango de valores que puede almacenar, este rango depende de si el dato es con o sin signo y de su tamaño en bits. Así pues:

- Los números de 8 bits pueden almacenar 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 valores.
- Los números de 16 bits pueden almacenar 2<sup>16</sup> = 65.536 valores.
- Los números de 32 bits pueden almacenar 2<sup>32</sup> = 4.294.967.296 valores.
- Los números de 64 bits pueden almacenar 2<sup>64</sup> = 18.446.744.073.709.551.616 valores.

En general, el tipo `int` es un entero de 32 bits con signo, lo que implica que (obviando el cero) la mitad de los valores almacenables serán positivos y la otra mitad negativos, lo que nos deja un rango (positivo) de 0 a 2.147.483.647… un valor **MUY** inferior a 777.777.777.777.777.777.777.772.

Así que, hagas lo que hagas, no puedes hacer caber un el valor mayor que setecientos setenta y siete mil setecientos setenta y siete trillones en una variable que (como mucho) puede almacenar valores hasta algo más de cuatro mil millones. Es por eso que al leer semejante valor en una variable cuyo rango de valores es muy inferior al número introducido, queda el flujo de consola (`std::cin`) en un estado erróneo:

```
int valor = 0;
std::cin >> valor; // Introducir 777777777777777777777772

std::cout << "El flujo de entrada esta en estado "
          << (std::cin.good() ? "correcto" : "incorrecto")
          << '\n';
```

El [código anterior muestra](https://tio.run/##dY8xD4IwEIVn@ite6gAMinExAcTJwf/g0rSV1ECPlNbF@NuxSNj0hru8y7187@QwbFspp2ljrOyC0qgNjd5p0TeMGevRC2OznL1YMqun6MjhhH3FktGrspTGommWfYWiwNV6RypI43D8XQe2eil41DX4pcO9Cw9C5OvoF0pAjz42@52KwFmSxNNshe5aIpXlOINLck5LTxwleHxjlfliSW82rSLSaR@cnZO/p@lvtA8):

> ```
> El flujo de entrada esta en estado incorrecto
> ```

Si realmente requieres analizar números de tamaño arbitrario, léelos como texto y analiza el último carácter:

```
std::string valor;
std::cin >> valor; // Introducir 777777777777777777777772

std::cout << "El flujo de entrada esta en estado "
    << (std::cin.good() ? "correcto" : "incorrecto")
    << '\n';

// Primero miramos si se ha introducido un número
if (std::all_of(valor.begin(), valor.end(), [](auto c) { return std::isdigit(c); }))
{
    // Después miramos si el último carácter es un número par.
    std::cout << valor << " es " << (((valor.back() - '0') % 2) ? "impar" : "par") << '\n';
}
else
    std::cout << valor << " no es un numero\n";
```

El [código anterior muestra](https://tio.run/##fZHNTsQgFIXX5SluakwhcX7ixmQ6qSsXPoNjDAJTUXpvQ8HETObZK@206iQqCwgnHM53QLXtolaq7y8sKhe1ga2lLngjm4p9a0mxWP9UpKvJ2/Bydkyp8NGaijGLARppkQt2YFkX9GZzugLepSNfTpqyCFU1abBawT0GTzoq6@Hm93HNZi/FANst5HcO9i6@EiQCk/xSSzBdSBOOqybIWZalo3wOXdZEmgu4hVyR90YFymEDeSoyb8XJUuywKFOk3U9u6dwT7fmIvHw29dDx6tRgaVAPm4dHLmMgUAIO4E2IHmH02k7b2gauRAlHkRLS25yXGe8ZWyX0NA3QfA6T6i0xL6BYFwIu4Xrkt00r/Qg/rAK@mLMjy4zrzD8RSENKRMDYGE87zIeqE/G6ZMe@//MXPgE):

> ```
> El flujo de entrada esta en estado correcto
> 777777777777777777777772 es par
> ```